# replace string in get_permalink() function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling to rewrite URLs. BC facebook doesn't follow 301 redirects for Likes (ugh) I'm needing to find a way to rewrite the `og:url` parameter wordpress spits out to get http in there instead of https.

I'm trying the following to no avail:

```
<?php 
$oldlink = get_permalink(get_the_id());
$newlink = str_replace('https', 'http', $oldlink);
?>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $newlink ?>"/>
```

Any ideas why this method might not work?

Comment: get_the_id works in the WP loop.

Comment: Why exactly cant you use https in the meta tag?

Comment: and what you retrieve from get_permalink(get_the_id()); ? false?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it in the header.php and the page you're loading is single post/page/custom post you can use the_post(); before your statement in order to initiate the loop.

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php $oldlink = get_permalink(get_the_id()); $newlink=str_replace('https','http',$oldlink); echo $newlink; ?>" />
```

The thing is that the get_the_id() function works only within the loop, so with out initiating it it returns fault results causing get_permalink function to return nothing useful.

But be careful, if you call the_post later again on the same single page after the first one it can mess up your data output. So be sure to call it only once per single page (if you're not creating custom loop of cource).